# How to hide html items with a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a beginner html/css/javascript question. I've been beating my head against a wall, but still can't figure this out. I have a simple web form that users fill out(name, email, etc) and the way it's supposed to work is that when the user clicks a radio button that says "Yes" they see a drop down menu with a set number of items and when they click "No" they see a text field. I have this part working correctly, but I want the drop down menu and text field to start hidden, and then appear when the yes or no radio button is clicked. I've tried `style = display:hidden;` but when I used this the text and drop-down menu wouldn't appear anymore.

Thanks so much for any answers!

This is the code I'm using:

```
<tr align="left" valign="middle">
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <p><b><font color="#cc0000" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="+2">*</font></b></p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <p>Do you own a Zaxwerks product?</p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <p><input id="customer" name="STATUS" onclick="javascript: test();" type="radio" value="Existing Customer" /> Yes<br />
    <input id="demo" name="STATUS" onclick="javascript: test();" type="radio" value="Downloaded Demo" /> No</p>
  </td>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function test() {
      if (document.getElementById('customer').checked) {
        //Show
        document.getElementById('show_customer').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('show_customer2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('show_customer3').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('show_customer4').style.display = 'block';

        //Hide
        document.getElementById('show_demo').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('show_demo2').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('show_demo3').style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        //Show
        document.getElementById('show_demo').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('show_demo2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('show_demo3').style.display = 'block';

        //Hide
        document.getElementById('show_customer').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('show_customer2').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('show_customer3').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('show_customer4').style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  </script>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="display: none;">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="display: none;">
    <div id="show_customer">
      <p><b><font color="#cc0000" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="+2">*</font></b></p>
    </div>

    <div id="show_demo" style="display: none;">
      <p><b><font color="#cc0000" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="+2">*</font></b></p>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="display: none;">
    <div id="show_customer2">
      <p>Product Owned:</p>
    </div>

    <div id="show_demo2" >
      <p>Where did you hear about us?:</p>
    </div>
  </td>
<!--This is where the user selects which product they own. (In the following code: value equals "what appears in the log file" what appears in the site menu)-->
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <div id="show_customer3" style="display: none;">
      <p><select id="WHAT" name="WHAT" size="1">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select One</option>
        <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
        <option value="Item 4">Item 4</option>
        <option value="Item 5">Item 5</option>
        <option value="Item 6">Item 6</option>
        <option value="Item 7">Item 8</option>
        <option value="Item 9">Item 9</option>
        <option value="Item 10">Item 10</option>
        <option value="Item 11">Item 11</option>
        <option value="Item 12">Item 12</option>
      </select></p>
    </div>

    <div id="show_demo3" style="display: none;">
      <p>
        <input maxlength="64" name="WHERE" size="30" type="text" value="" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `display:none` you use in other places in your code. Specifically these lines

```
<div id="show_customer2" style="display: none;">
  <p>Product Owned:</p>
</div>

<div id="show_demo2" style="display: none;">
  <p>Where did you hear about us?:</p>
</div>
```

Here is a working example:

```html
<tr align="left" valign="middle">
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <p><b><font color="#cc0000" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="+2">*</font></b></p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <p>Do you own a Zaxwerks product?</p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <p><input id="customer" name="STATUS" onclick="javascript: test();" type="radio" value="Existing Customer" /> Yes<br />
    <input id="demo" name="STATUS" onclick="javascript: test();" type="radio" value="Downloaded Demo" /> No</p>
  </td>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function test() {
      if (document.getElementById('customer').checked) {
        //Show
        document.getElementById('show_customer').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('show_customer2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('show_customer3').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('show_customer4').style.display = 'block';

        //Hide
        document.getElementById('show_demo').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('show_demo2').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('show_demo3').style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        //Show
        document.getElementById('show_demo').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('show_demo2').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('show_demo3').style.display = 'block';

        //Hide
        document.getElementById('show_customer').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('show_customer2').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('show_customer3').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('show_customer4').style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  </script>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="display: none;">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="display: none;">
    <div id="show_customer">
      <p><b><font color="#cc0000" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="+2">*</font></b></p>
    </div>

    <div id="show_demo" style="display: none;">
      <p><b><font color="#cc0000" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="+2">*</font></b></p>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="display: none;">
    <div id="show_customer2" style="display: none;">
      <p>Product Owned:</p>
    </div>

    <div id="show_demo2" style="display: none;">
      <p>Where did you hear about us?:</p>
    </div>
  </td>
<!--This is where the user selects which product they own. (In the following code: value equals "what appears in the log file" what appears in the site menu)-->
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <div id="show_customer3" style="display: none;">
      <p><select id="WHAT" name="WHAT" size="1">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select One</option>
        <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
        <option value="Item 4">Item 4</option>
        <option value="Item 5">Item 5</option>
        <option value="Item 6">Item 6</option>
      </select></p>
    </div>

    <div id="show_demo3" style="display: none;">
      <p>
        <input maxlength="64" name="WHERE" size="30" type="text" value="" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you depperm for your help! This does hide the text field and dropdown, however when you click on the radio buttons the text items don't show up so the formatting is off.

Comment: The text items "Product Owned" and "Where did you hear about us?"

Comment: Did you run the snipped? The text appears/disappears with the corresponding textfield/combo

Comment: Oh that's really odd, you are correct. It works nicely in the code snippet, but when I paste your exact code into dreamweaver it messes with all of my formatting and I can't see the text items. Weird.

Comment: What do you recommend using instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to restructure some of your information, this can easily be done with CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

.customers , .demo{
    display:none;
}
#customer[type="radio"]:checked ~ .customers{
   display:block;
}
#demo[type="radio"]:checked ~ .demo{
   display:block;
}


</style>


<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <input id="customer" name="STATUS" type="radio" value="Existing Customer" /> Yes
    <input id="demo" name="STATUS" type="radio" value="Downloaded Demo" /> No
   <div class="customers">
      <p>Product Owned:</p>
    </div>

    <div class="demo">
      <p>Where did you hear about us?:</p>
    </div>      



</td>
</tr>
</table>
```